# How to properly send method from C# 9.0 to C/C++ library using C# 9.0 new delegate*?

Tags: c#, c++, c, glfw, c#-9.0

**NOTICE**: Using dotnet version 5.0.100-rc.2.20479.15

So, as the title says, I'm trying to figure out how to properly send a function from C# 9.0 to a C/C++ code library (glfw for example) and use that function as a callback method (i.e. for the error callback).

With the introduction of the delegate*<> syntax in C# 9.0, I've been trying to send a delegate from C# as an IntPtr to a function in C/C++ that in C# is visible as a delegate*<>.

For this example I have prepared a test project that simulates the behavior I'm getting and what I'm trying to accomplish in the code. I have two functions in my C/C++ library (taking place of GLFW in this case), `SetErrorCallbackFunction` and `InvokeError`.

1. `SetErrorCallbackFunction`: Sets the error callback method via function pointer defined as `typedef void (*ERRORcallback)(int error_code, const char* description);`
2. `InvokeError`: Simulates the error callback function set from `SetErrorCallbackFunction` being called due to an error somewhere else in the code.

In the C# code I have a library class called `Util` that gives me the function pointer from the C/C++ Library as a `delegate*<IntPtr, void>` for `SetErrorCallbackFunction`.

In the main method, I call SetErrorCallback that takes in an `Action<int, string>` as an argument (the method I want to run when the errorcallback is called). This method sets a delegate, `_ErrorCallback` equal to a lambda function which converts the byte* description to a string and calls the `Action<int, string> errorCallback` parameter with `error_code` and newly produced string. That lambda/delegate is then converted into an IntPtr from `Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(_ErrorCallback)` and is ultimately what's sent to the C/C++ library.

When running the code though, I get the output:

```
Set errorCallback
Invoking error
Fatal error. Invalid Program: attempted to call a UnmanagedCallersOnly method from managed code.
```

The Fatal error line is produced when the `InvokeError` method tries to call `errorCallback`.
This is kind of the only way I can see doing this with the behavior that I want. I don't want to have to deal with byte* in the highest level of the code (in the main method, I'd rather give the function a lambda with an int and a string rather than an int and a byte*).

The `SECOND EXAMPLE` in the code is an alternate way of doing it, but still isn't ideal because I'd have to use the byte* like I previously stated I didn't want to do at a "higher level" of code per se).

The `SECOND EXAMPLE` code output is as follows:

```
Set errorCallback
Invoking error
Error 4 - Custom Description
```

I have also tried these different argument types for the delegate*:

```
private static delegate*<Delegate, void> SetErrorCallbackFunction = (delegate*<Delegate, void>)Util.StaticProcAddressPointer("SetErrorCallbackFunction");
```

```
private static delegate*<ErrorCallbackDelegate, void> SetErrorCallbackFunction = (delegate*<ErrorCallbackDelegate, void>)Util.StaticProcAddressPointer("SetErrorCallbackFunction");
```

but they both have the same issue.

If anyone has any idea on what I may be doing incorrectly or if the Fatal Error is just how C# 9.0 works with delegate* then please let me know. If you don't understand my long winded explanation or need clarification/more detail then also please let me know and I'll update the post with more information.

Thank you!

### Edits:

Edit1: Included a Wrapper class in C# to show a more clearly that I want the conversion of the byte* to string to be abstracted away from the main code.

Edit2: Include dotnet version I'm using.

Edit3: As `madreflection` mentioned, I am indeed missing an `unmanaged` keyword on the declaration of the `InvokeError` method. This however, is on purpose. Adding the `unmanaged` keyword will cause the code to work as expected, though, for example, using a library where there is no `InvokeError` method that is exposed, the `unmanaged` keyword isn't able to be used anywhere. Therefor, in order for the example to match using a library like GLFW where the errorCallback method is managed entirely by the unmanaged code, the `InvokeError` method declaration does not include the `unmanaged` keyword.

Edit4: GLFW Example below:

Output:
Fatal error. Invalid Program: attempted to call a UnmanagedCallersOnly method from managed code.

GLFW Example:

```cs
using System;
using System.Text;

namespace Test
{
    public static unsafe class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // GLFW Example
            {
                GlfwWrapper.SetErrorCallback((error_code, description) =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Error {error_code} - {description}");
                });
                GlfwWrapper.CreateWindow(1280, 720, "Title", IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

```cs
using System;
using System.Text;

namespace Test
{
    public unsafe class GlfwWrapper
    {
        // GLFW example
        public static delegate*<IntPtr, void> glfwSetErrorCallback = (delegate*<IntPtr, void>)GlfwUtil.StaticProcAddressPointer("glfwSetErrorCallback");
        public static delegate*<int, int, byte*, IntPtr, IntPtr, IntPtr> glfwCreateWindow = (delegate*<int, int, byte*, IntPtr, IntPtr, IntPtr>)GlfwUtil.StaticProcAddressPointer("glfwCreateWindow");

// Delegate that matches the function signature in C/C++ library
        public unsafe delegate void ErrorCallbackDelegate(int error_code, byte* description);
        // Delegate stored so it doesn't get garbage collected.
        public static ErrorCallbackDelegate _ErrorCallback;

        public static void SetErrorCallback(IntPtr errorCallback){
            _ErrorCallback = (error_code, description) =>
            {
                byte* walk = description;
                while (*walk != 0) walk++;

                errorCallback(error_code, Encoding.UTF8.GetString(description, (int)(walk - description)));
            };
            glfwSetErrorCallback(Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(_ErrorCallback));
        }

        public static IntPtr CreateWindow(int width, int height, string title, IntPtr monitor, IntPtr share)
        {
            fixed (byte* ptr = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(title))
            {
                return glfwCreateWindow(width, height, ptr, monitor, share);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Code:

C# 9.0 Code:

```cs
using System;
using System.Text;

namespace Test
{
    public static unsafe class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Wrapper.SetErrorCallback((error_code, description) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Error {error_code} - {description}");
            });
            // I want to avoid this (1/2)
            // Wrapper.SetErrorCallback((error_code, description) =>
            // {
            //     byte* walk = description;
            //     while (*walk != 0) walk++;
            //     Console.WriteLine($"Error {error_code} - {Encoding.UTF8.GetString(description, (int)(walk - description))}");
            // });
            Wrapper.InvokeError();

            // SECOND EXAMPLE -----------------------------------------
            // This will work but the issue with having to write a method each time with a byte* is not ideal.
            Wrapper.SetErrorCallbackFunctionSECOND_EXAMPLE(&ErrorCallback);
            Wrapper.InvokeError();
            // SECOND EXAMPLE -----------------------------------------
        }

        // SECOND EXAMPLE
        public static void ErrorCallback(int error_code, byte* description)
        {
            byte* walk = description;
            while (*walk != 0) walk++;

            Console.WriteLine($"Error {error_code} - {Encoding.UTF8.GetString(description, (int)(walk - description))}");
        }
    }
}
```

```cs
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;

namespace Test
{
    public unsafe class Wrapper
    {
        // delegate* to InvokeError C/C++ function
        public static delegate*<void> InvokeError = (delegate*<void>)Util.StaticProcAddressPointer("InvokeError");
        // delegate* to SetErrorCallbackFunction C/C++ function
        public static delegate*<IntPtr, void> SetErrorCallbackFunction = (delegate*<IntPtr, void>)Util.StaticProcAddressPointer("SetErrorCallbackFunction");

        // SECOND EXAMPLE --------------------------------------------------
        public static delegate*<delegate*<int, byte*, void>, void> SetErrorCallbackFunctionSECOND_EXAMPLE = (delegate*<delegate*<int, byte*, void>, void>)Util.StaticProcAddressPointer("SetErrorCallbackFunction");
        // SECOND EXAMPLE --------------------------------------------------

        // Delegate that matches the function signature in C/C++ library
        public unsafe delegate void ErrorCallbackDelegate(int error_code, byte* description);
        // Delegate stored so it doesn't get garbage collected.
        public static ErrorCallbackDelegate _ErrorCallback;

        // Method to set the error callback.
        public static void SetErrorCallback(Action<int, string> errorCallback)
        {
            // By doing it here (2/2)
            _ErrorCallback = (error_code, description) =>
            {
                byte* walk = description;
                while (*walk != 0) walk++;

                errorCallback(error_code, Encoding.UTF8.GetString(description, (int)(walk - description)));
            };
            SetErrorCallbackFunction(Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(_ErrorCallback));
        }
    }
}
```

C Library:

```cpp
#include "library.h"

ERRORcallback errorCallback;

void SetErrorCallbackFunction(ERRORcallback callback)
{
    errorCallback = callback;
    std::cout << "Set errorCallback" << std::endl;
}

void InvokeError()
{
    std::cout << "Invoking error" << std::endl;
    errorCallback(4, "Custom Description");
}
```

```cpp
#pragma once
#include <iostream>

typedef void (*ERRORcallback)(int error_code, const char* description);
extern "C"
{
    __attribute__((visibility("default"))) void SetErrorCallbackFunction(ERRORcallback callback);
    __attribute__((visibility("default"))) void InvokeError();
}
```

Comment: Quick stab: missing the `unmanaged` keyword in the function pointer type.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/function-pointers Might need `unmanaged[Cdecl]` at that.

Comment: @madreflection Indeed you are correct, changing

`public static delegate*<void> InvokeError = (delegate*<void>)Util.StaticProcAddressPointer("InvokeError");`

to

`public static delegate* unmanaged<void> InvokeError = (delegate* unmanaged<void>)Util.StaticProcAddressPointer("InvokeError");`


does make the code work as expected. However, in the case of using a library like GLFW, I do not have control over the method that invokes the errorcallback so I can't add the unmanaged keyword anywhere like I can in the example. Thank you for the suggestion and time though!

Comment: @madreflection using `unmanaged` alone will cause the code to run fine, though that isn't the main issue. The `InvokeError` method is only there as a means to roughly replicate an error from GLFW. i.e. if you forgot to initialize GLFW before creating a window, it will run the errorCallback function set. That function is called and managed entirely by GLFW. In the case of the example the only way to easily replicate the errorCallback being used is by creating the `InvokeError` method. (1/2)

Comment: @madreflection  In the "real world" scenario of GLFW, there is no method that is exposed that invokes the error as it is completely up to the library. When using GLFW it will give me the same `Fatal error.` message with or without the `unmanaged` keyword in front of the delegate* declarations. (2/2)

Comment: I'm back to thinking you need `unmanaged[Cdecl]` to match the `__cdecl` used by GLFW; also you may need to add something like `[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]` to your method. If the function in GLFW that's calling the errorCallback is expecting to pop the parameters off the stack (__cdecl) but the function it called (yours) already did so (__stdcall) (assuming `unmanaged` without calling convention defaults to `__stdcall`), that would certainly cause an error of a fatal nature. I don't know what GLFW is doing so I'm still just taking stabs in the dark.

Comment: @madreflection I'll keep messing around with your suggestions for a bit and edit my post with any new things I find. Thank you very much for your time and effort!

Comment: @madreflection Adding the `[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]` to the delegate and adding `unmanaged[Cdecl]` to **all** methods fixed the issue. Much thanks! I'll answer the post very soon with that explanation and thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Much thanks to @madreflection. Adding the `[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]` to the delegate and adding `unmanaged[Cdecl]` to **all** delegate* functions fixed the issue. I was unaware that the default is `__stdcall`.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use DllImport:

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
public unsafe class Wrapper
{
    public unsafe delegate void dg(int x, byte* y);
    [DllImport("glfw3.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr glfwCreateWindow(int width, int height, byte* title, IntPtr monitor, IntPtr share);
    [DllImport("glfw3.dll")]
    public static extern void glfwSetErrorCallback(System.IntPtr f);

    // Method to set the error callback.
    public static dg _ErrorCallback;
    public static void SetErrorCallback(Action<int, string> errorCallback)
    {
        _ErrorCallback = (error_code, description) =>
        {
            byte* walk = description;
            while (*walk != 0) walk++;
            errorCallback(error_code, Encoding.UTF8.GetString(description, (int)(walk - description)));
        };

        glfwSetErrorCallback(Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(_ErrorCallback));
    }
    public static IntPtr CreateWindow(int width, int height, string title, IntPtr monitor, IntPtr share)
    {
        fixed (byte* ptr = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(title))
        {
            return glfwCreateWindow(width, height, ptr, monitor, share);
        }
    }
}
public static unsafe class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Wrapper.SetErrorCallback((error_code, description) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Error {error_code} - {description}");
        });

        Wrapper.CreateWindow(1280, 720, "Title", IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```